# Redirecting the output of service in Ubuntu to Log files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, redirection, systemd

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and deployed a service in `/etc/systemd/system`. 
The service file `booster.service` contains

```
[Unit]
Description = booster
After = network.target
[Service]
ExecStart =/opt/tech/mybooster/sbin/booster_server
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=booster 
[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

One more file in the `/etc/rsyslog.d` named `25-booster.conf` has the following contents

```
:syslogtag, isequal, "ubooster" /opt/tech/mybooster/logs/booster_server.log
& stop
```

I am able to see the logs from the command `journalctl -u booster`.
But the logs are not getting redirected to the `booster_server.log` file.

I have gone through this link [redirecting the systemd output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585758/how-to-redirect-output-of-systemd-service-to-a-file),but as mentioned in the comments its not working on 16.04.

I have tried the option of changing to `if $programname == ...` but it didn't work.

The last comment in the accepted answer, where the user mentioned about changing the user to `syslog`. So I have changed both `owner` and `group` to `syslog` but even this is of no use.

Any comments ?

EDIT 1: I have also read that if `systemd` version is 236 or above, the log file absolute path can be provided directly to the `StandardOutput` and `StandardError` in `.service` file. But the `systemd` version in my system is 229 and many have cautioned of upgrading `systemd` until and unless a person has considerable experience of working on Linux. As there are more chances that it will break the system than being successful.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the same link provide in the question but some of the users have cautioned using it. But it can be used as a temporary solution. If any body has a better solution please provide.

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37595720/7984479)